# How to locally shift values in a numpy array by arrays of shifts?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say, I have an initial 2D array with some numbers:

```py
initial = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                    [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

and two another arrays of the same shape: the first one contains unit shifts by rows, the second one - by columns (assuming, that they are constructed to avoid getting out of bounds):

```py
rowShifts = np.array([[0, 0,  1, 0],
                      [0, 0, -1, 0]])

colShifts = np.array([[0, 1, 0, -1],
                      [0, 0, 1,  0]])
```

How can I get an array, which coincides with the initial one, except the elements, that should be shifted in accordance with these two arrays?

```py
result = np.array([[1, 3, 7, 3],
                   [5, 6, 4, 8]])
```

Obviously, it can be done using loops, but in the real situation the performance will be unacceptable.

Another possible solution, which can come into mind, is to make copies of initial array with constant shifts and select the values by condition, but for large 3D arrays this approach will cost too large amount of memory.

Is there any appropriate solution, which will be not so heavy in terms of memory and performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a grid, offset, and index.

---

```
xs, ys = initial.shape
rm, cm = np.ogrid[:xs, :ys]

initial[rm + rowShifts, cm + colShifts]
```

```
array([[1, 3, 7, 3],
       [5, 6, 4, 8]])
```

Comment: Use `ogrid` for efficiency?

Comment: Yes, definitely preferable!

Answer (score 2):

If shifts are rare, i.e. if there are many zeros in rowShifts/colShifts then a sparse scheme may save a bit of time. Experimenting with a 1000x1000 grid I see cross over at about 20% nonzero shifts:

[image]

```
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder, MultiArgument
import numpy as np

B = BenchmarkBuilder()

@B.add_function()
def ogrid(data,rowo,colo):
    xs, ys = data.shape
    rm, cm = np.ogrid[:xs, :ys]
    return data[rm + rowo, cm + colo]

@B.add_function()
def sparse(data,rowo,colo):
    nz = np.where(rowo.astype(bool) | colo.astype(bool))
    result = data.copy()
    result[nz] = data[nz[0]+rowo[nz],nz[1]+colo[nz]]
    return result

@B.add_arguments('number of shiftees')
def argument_provider():
    data = np.arange(1000000).reshape(1000,1000)
    for exp in range(8, 40):
        nsh = int(1.4**exp)
        shifts = np.random.randint(0,1000,(2,2,nsh))
        rowo = np.zeros((1000,1000),int)
        colo = np.zeros((1000,1000),int)
        rowo[shifts[0,0],shifts[1,0]] = shifts[0,1]-shifts[0,0]
        colo[shifts[0,0],shifts[1,0]] = shifts[1,1]-shifts[1,0]
        yield np.count_nonzero(rowo.astype(bool) | colo.astype(bool)), \
            MultiArgument([data,rowo,colo])

r = B.run()
r.plot()

import pylab
pylab.savefig('bm.png')
```